# Can I create an array with randomized individual spacings?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

As background, I am working on a blend file which can represent the majority of plantlife via shape keys, array modifiers, curves, and curve follows. I have the leaf keys down (25 of them) and so far, it's working great, save for one thing.

I am simulating rosette leaves by adding an array modifier to the leaf mesh, and then having it follow a curve. While some symmetry exists in nature, the level of perfection I'm getting is killing the believability. (See screenshot.)
[image]
I could get around this if I could have the array spacing be jarred somewhat, that is, had a noise component between each mesh. One might be 0.9 units away, the next might be 0.82, the next 0.95, you get the idea. Unfortunately, aside from diving into Python, I have no idea how to do something like that.

Is it possible? If so, how?